Nifi ExecuteSQLRecord Avro Schema Inference
We have recently upgraded Nifi from version 1.11.4 to 1.27.
An unexpected issue has cropped up where the ExecuteSQLRecord processor avro schema inference behaviour appears to have changed. Specifically, Oracle Number datatypes with decimals are now being inferred as integers. We can correct this issue by using a specified avro schema within the AvroSetRecordWriter associated with the ExecuteSQLRecord, but this adds additional complexity and overhead to our development activities.
I feel I need to understand the processor behaviour a little more before committing to using this work around. For instance, the AvroSetRecordWriter Schema Access Strategy was originally set to Inherit. Does this mean the ExecuteSQLRecord processor is making its own data type inference? Or does the first inference come from the AvroSetRecordWriter if there hasn't been any inference made so far?
Thanks.
